# I can not seem to create any of my objects in my main?

Tags: java

The point of the program is to display a poker and bridge hand. Those far when I run the program I can get it to display the poker description and then if exits. I would like it to continue and display the a poker hand then the bridge description and a bridge hand. I feel like my issues are coming from the abstract DeckOfCards class but Im really not sure.

I put all the classes in the same file to make it easier to follow and edit while programming.

When the program fails it gives these errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 52
at DeckOfCards.creatCardDeck(PlayCardGames.java:106)
at DeckOfCards.DeckOfCards(PlayCardGames.java:95)
at PlayCardGames.main(PlayCardGames.java:14)
```

Here is the program code it self (Thank you for editing it to format better)

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class PlayCardGames {

       public static void main(String[] args) {


           Poker playPoker = new Poker();
           playPoker.DeckOfCards();
           playPoker.displayDescription();
           playPoker.deal();

           Bridge playBridge = new Bridge();
           playBridge.DeckOfCards();
           playBridge.displayDescription();
           playBridge.deal();


       }

    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\\

    interface DeckConstants{
       final static int CARDS_IN_SUIT = 13;
       final static int SUITS_IN_DECK = 4;
       final static int CARDS_IN_DECK = CARDS_IN_SUIT * SUITS_IN_DECK;
    }

    //================================================================================\\

    class Card{

       private String suit;
       private String rank;
       private int rankIndex;

       public Card(int suitIndex, int rankIndex){
           setSuit(suitIndex);
           setRank(rankIndex);
    }

    public String getSuit() {
        if (suit.equalsIgnoreCase("Hearts")){ suit = "\u2665";}
        else if (suit.equalsIgnoreCase("Diamonds")) { suit = "\u2666"; }
        else if (suit.equalsIgnoreCase("Clubs")) { suit = "\u2663"; }
        else if(suit.equalsIgnoreCase("Spades")) { suit = "\u2660"; }

        return suit;
    }

    public void setSuit(int suitIndex) {
        if (suitIndex == 1) {suit = "Spades";}
        else if (suitIndex == 2) {suit = "Hearts";}
        else if (suitIndex == 3) {suit = "Diamonds";}
        else if(suitIndex == 4) {suit = "Clubs";}

    }

    public String getRank() {
        if (rankIndex == 1) {rank = "Ace";}
        else if (rankIndex == 11) {rank = "Jack";}
        else if (rankIndex == 12) {rank = "Queen";}
        else if(rankIndex == 13) {rank = "King";}

        return rank;
    }

    public void setRank(int rankIndex) {
        if (this.rankIndex >= 13){
            this.rankIndex = 13;}
        else if(this.rankIndex <= 1) {
            this.rankIndex = 1;}

    }

    public String toString(String rank, String suit) {
        return getRank() +" of " + getSuit();
    }

    }

    //=================================================================================\\

    abstract class DeckOfCards implements DeckConstants{

       protected Card[] deck = new Card[CARDS_IN_DECK];

       public void DeckOfCards(){
        creatCardDeck();
        shuffle(deck);
    }

       public void creatCardDeck() {
        int numberOfCards = 0;

        for (int suitCounter = 1; suitCounter < CARDS_IN_SUIT; suitCounter++)
        {
            for (int rankCounter = 1; rankCounter < CARDS_IN_SUIT; rankCounter++)
            {
                deck[numberOfCards] = new Card(suitCounter, rankCounter);
                numberOfCards++;
            }
        }
    }

    public void shuffle(Card[] temp){
        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int k = temp.length; k > 1; k--){
            int i = k - 1;
            int j = rnd.nextInt(k);

            Card tmp = temp[i];
            temp[i] = temp[j];
            temp[j]= tmp;

        }
    }

    public abstract void displayDescription();

    public abstract void deal();

    }

    //===============================================================================\\

    class Poker extends DeckOfCards{
       private int cardsDealt = 5;
       private int index = 0;

    public void Poker(){
        displayDescription();
        deal();
    }

    public void displayDescription(){
        String desc = "In poker, players bet on hands" +
                   "\n Winner can bluff or must have the highest hand if called";

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, desc);

    }

    public void deal() {

        String message = "Your Poker hand:\n";

        for (int x = index; x < cardsDealt; x++){
            message += deck[index] + "\n";
            index++;
        }

        if (index == CARDS_IN_DECK){
            shuffle(deck);
            index = 0;
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
    }


}

    //===============================================================================\\

    class Bridge extends DeckOfCards{
       private int cardsDealt = 13;
       private int index = 0;

    public void Bridge(){
        displayDescription();
        deal();
    }

    public void displayDescription(){
        String desc = "In bride, partners bid on how many tricks they will take." +
                "\n The high bid determines a trump suit";

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, desc);

    }

    public void deal() {
        String message = "Your Bridge hand:\n";

        for (int x = index; x < cardsDealt; x++){
            message += deck[index] + "\n";
            index++;
        }

        if (index == CARDS_IN_DECK){
            shuffle(deck);
            index = 0;
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the problem? Did you try to compile your code and and get an error? If yes, please share your error stack.

Comment: Still reading through this. There is a lot of code. You would do well to help us help you, by narrowing down your problem. I have to say though, I have never seen anyone use an interface for static variables. I am not the biggest expert in the world, but that looks very very wrong. Maybe use an abstract class instead?

Comment: Oh, you already have an abstract class implement the deckconstants! Lose the interface, and add them directly to the deck of cards!

Comment: I don't necessarily think declaring constants in an interface is wrong but KjetilNordin has a point. Since abstract class DeckOfCards implements the interface, constants could be declared in the abstract class instead.

Comment: @KjetilNordin I added the interface to learn how to use it. The ultimate goal of the program is to display in a JOption window the poker and bridge description (the poker description will display) and then display a hand for both objects. Thus far the program quits after displaying the poker description window

Comment: @KjetilNordin That would be the [constant interface anti-pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_interface), which is frowned upon. Your instincts are correct

Comment: @RickySchiebner, well you are learning the syntax. And starting programming in any new language is a swamp full of fallpits when it comes to best practices and conventions. Syntax today, intended uses, and conventions tomorrow. You'll be great :) Still too much code dump for me to find your problem tonight. Central European bedtime now, so I don't have the time to import all of your code into a project, and run it.

Comment: Aside from the interface which I see now is very redundant is there anything glaringly wrong?

Comment: @KjetilNordin Your good, I really appreciate your time ether way.

Comment: Just took a final look, after I saw your IndexOutOfBoundsException. Those are usually pretty manageable ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know what, I think it is really simple:
Here is your code:

```
for (int suitCounter = 1; suitCounter < CARDS_IN_SUIT; suitCounter++)
        {
            for (int rankCounter = 1; rankCounter < CARDS_IN_SUIT; rankCounter++)
            {
```

I think just maybe it should be:

```
for (int suitCounter = 1; suitCounter < SUITS_IN_DECK; suitCounter++)
            {
                for (int rankCounter = 1; rankCounter < CARDS_IN_SUIT; rankCounter++)
                {
```

Comment: You had it right, using a counter starting at 0 index, when adding to the array. But when you tried to add 13 different suits, you'd end up with more than 52 cards anyway, and your array just can't handle that :)

Comment: I wish you could see this smile :) :) :) That nailed it. For the most part. Now I am getting all my windows and its displaying Cards but instead of display Ace of hearts is displaying Card@38hdshf (or Card@+jargon)

Comment: Man Iv been hovering over this all day its always the small things. I really appreciate your help its such a relief.

Comment: Just give me my internet points, and I'll go look in a mirror to see a smile ;). Honestly I love this site, and it feels awesome to finally be at a level where I can contribute, instead of only receiving help all the time.

Comment: ...You give me points by clicking on the grey V next to my answer, by the way ;). Then it becomes green! (In case you are new here, and welcome)

Comment: Given, you earned them, Thank you

Comment: btw, your other problem can be fixed by overriding the `toString()`-method